# Saving a view shows "This display has no path"

Tags: views

I have migrated my website to a new host. Now, the front page logo is missing and  dynamic block contents became static.

On editing a view block, it shows:

> All changes are stored temporarily. Click Save to make your changes permanent. Click Cancel to discard your changes.

On updating the preview, it shows "This display has no path."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the view have a path ? please some more details about your view.

Comment: This can happen if your view is disabled. Should work as expected once enabled.